# Reload UITableView during search

Tags: uitableview, search, plist, nspredicate

I have a tableview with data loaded from an array (from a plist) and i have also got the search bar working with NSPredicate. Only problem is that when i search the results show the original data not the filtered data. Also when I click cancel it show the correct number of results but using the unfiltered data. How do I make the table view show the filtered data when the search bar is active and after kicking search?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[table reloadData]` (or one of the other reload methods) to indicate to a table view that the source data has mutated.

Comment: I now get "index (10) beyond bounds (1)'" on line:

Comment: searchdict = [filteredData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //which comes before  cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"itemTitle"];

Comment: That's the NSArray filteredData complaining that the table view is requesting row 10 but it has only 1 thing in it. Is your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returning the correct number when you want to display search results?